# iTextSharp table.SpacingBefore not working

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a table which I'm trying to space down about 20/30 floating points (f) from the top margin of a pdf document. The reason I want to space down a bit is because I have a rectangle border running around the margin of my pdf document.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
table.SpacingAfter = 20f;
table.TotalWidth = 700f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
```

`table.SpacingAfter` works perfectly well but `table.SpacingBefore` will not, my table just sits at the top margin and will not space/pad down at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the [answer here](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PdfPTable-setSpacingBefore-not-honoured-if-pdfptable-added-as-first-element-to-document-tp2162942p2162943.html) that says that if a table is inserted as the first item in a document then `SpacingBefore` is ignored and that is by design. According to the post the solution is to add an empty paragraph with zero leading.

Comment: adding some sample code to the answer would be helpful, the link could go down then there would be no sample.

Comment: the paragraph should be with `new Paragraph(" ")` witch is different than `new Paragraph(string.Empty)`